# lnk2019 unreloved external symbols

Tags: c++, function

Error      9              error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals  D:\AUL_C++\AUL_2_C++_Version_02132015\AUL\Debug\AUL.exe
                1              1              AUL

Error      8              error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
"public: double __thiscall AULIV::ART_AV_RollForward(class AULIV *,class assets *,int &,int &,double &)" (?ART_AV_RollForward@AULIV@@QAENPAV1@PAVassets@@AAH2AAN@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl AUL_ReserveSetup(class AULIV *,class assets *,int,int,int,int)" (?AUL_ReserveSetup@@YAXPAVAULIV@@PAVassets@@HHHH@Z)                D:\AUL_C++\AUL_2_C++_Version_02132015\AUL\AUL\Main.obj                AUL

```
   //AUL Projection
   void AUL_ReserveSetup(AULIV* AUL_proj, assets* asset_proj, int &AUL_start_num, int &AUL_size_num, int &AUL_end_num, int &maxProjMth);

   //ART Calc
   double ART_AV_RollForward(AULIV* AUL_proj, assets* asset_proj, int &PolNum, int &t, double &PremPaid);

   void ART_SolveIni_Var(const int &TIME);
   void ART_SolveDel_Var();

   double* ART_accumNLG_Target;
   double* ART_accumNLG_Excess;
   double* ART_accumPremPaid;

   //AUL Projection
   void AUL_Projection(AULIV* AUL_proj, assets* asset_proj, int scen_start, int scen_end, int AUL_start, int AUL_size, int AUL_end, int maxProjMth);               

   double calcDB_Amt(AULIV* AUL_proj, const int &polNum, const double &AV_COI);
```

---

from void AUL_ReserveSetup
/////////////////////
'''''''''''''''''''''

```
   AUL_proj->ART_SolveIni_Var(PolYrMax);

          for (PolYear=0; PolYear <= PolYrMax; PolYear++)
          {
                 AttAge = AUL_proj->ALL_issue_age[polNumber] + PolYear - 1;

                     double    p0, p1, f0, f1, pDel, der;
                       int       i, ret;

                       p0  = max(10, AUL_proj->ALL_NLG_Target_prem[polNumber]);
                       f0  = AUL_proj->ART_AV_RollForward(AUL_proj, asset_proj, polNumber, PolYear, p0);

                       if (f0 < 0)
                              {
                              pDel       = 1;
                              }
                       else
                              {
                               pDel       = -1;
                              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `ART_AV_RollForward` function, but you did not define it. `ART_AV_RollForward` got added to the symbol table since you declared it, but since you did not provide it's definition, it could never be resolved.